# Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android

Please tell me  - Where I should write this code?

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.*;

Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
Message message = new Message.Builder(regId).build();
Result result = sender.send(message, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked the GCM demo application in Developer Android ?[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html)  is the link.
You will find a demo application and you check how they did it, then you can see where you are wrong. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code even from simple java console application.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
   Message message = new Message.Builder(regId).build();
   Result result = sender.send(message, 5);
}
```

necessary libraries: `gcm-server.jar`, `json_simple-1.1.jar`, `junit.jar`, `mockito-all-1.8.5.jar`.